# Session destroy of inactive users if inactivity at browser

Tags: php, session

This is bit different scenario in session management.
I want to develop as system where if users loges in and then keep shows activity on browser his session will continue and if no activity session will destroy.

For example user logged in at abc.com after that if he access google.com , yahoo.com, etc any website his session will be continue at abc.com else session will be destroy.

Its some thing like UTM device where user logged in once and they continue use system for a fix period of time..

Please help me with your suggestions to implement solution for above?
Thank you

Comment: isn't it the default behavior of browser? keep the sessions till closing browser.

Comment: if user is not active on browser. Once logged in in my website he should access other websites. if not accessing for any time period means he is inactive on browser, then destroy his session from my website.

Comment: not sure what you are asking, are you wanting the session to be destroyed if they are not actively using your web site or destroyed when no activity at all?

Comment: do you think any standard browser is going to send you details of what the user is doing with other sites? isn't there something called **privacy**

Comment: squid is a proxy server (not firewall). and it is designed to manage and log network traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to do it using cron jobs and database table "logging" where i maintained entry of logged in users. In one table storing website accessed by user and accessed time, if difference of last web accessed time and current time is more than 3 minutes removing the entry of user from logging table. If there are some more options available to do it please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A session is maintained server-side and you need requests to this server to renew the session. If the user requests pages from another server, your own server will and **should not** be informed.

While it may or may not be possible to write some hacks with JavaScript, you would violate the privacy of the user. This hack could and surely would be used to sniff users.

If you only want to be tolerant in your session timeout, simply choose a longer timeout (extend it to an hour if necessary). Then a user has enough time to browse other sites and still keep the session on your site. All other reasons to collect user requests i can think of, are spyware related.